# Get user details from people picker field using JQuery

Tags: jquery, people-picker

[image: Shared with Image]

I want to display user email address instead of user name when any user is selected from people picker using JQuery.

In People Picker control when any name is entered I want to display user's "Email" instead of user's "Display Name"

Answer (score 1):

Check this answer i gave for how to implement PeoplePicker using JSOM for sharepoint 2013.

[PeoplePicker using JSOM](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/134063/peoplepicker-using-jsom/134955#134955)

You can add following function in above solution and call this function.

```
function GetUserInfo(){
        var pplPicker = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict.peoplePickerspanId_TopSpan;
        var userInfo = pplPicker.GetAllUserInfo();  
    }
```

Here "userInfo" variable will contain details of all the user that is selected in PeoplePicker field.

Answer (score 0):

Check this other answer I gave someone else. It didn't solve their specific issue but it definitely worked for me.

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/154085/33297

The snippet uses SP.ClientContext only because the OP for that question needed it for something else. You can definitely do without that. My snippet also doesn't even need jquery.

Something like this should work:

```
    var pickerDiv = document.getElementById("<ID of people picker element>");      
    var peoplePicker = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[pickerDiv.id];
    var theUser = peoplePicker.GetAllUserInfo();
    var theUserId = theUser[0].EntityData.SPUserID;
    alert("SP User ID: " + theUserId);
```

If you inspect the peoplePicker array in your browser console you will see the other properties available. Email should be one of them.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I dont want to use ClientContext, I only want simple JQuery

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I've fixed the answer for you. It is essentially the same as Rohit's though.